# Validation and Fancybox popup upon Form Submit

Tags: jquery, validation, fancybox

In a form with this kind of action :

```
<form action="email.php">
```

Actual behavior :

- When user clicks submit, the form is checked using jQuery validate.
- If all is OK, data is submitted, and *user is sent to the email.php page*.

Desired behavior :

- When user clicks on Submit,
- data is checked
- if all is OK, submit data and *open a popup (with fancybox or alike) with a message*

How to all that upon the submit button's click ?

Validation alone is OK, as is Fancybox. 
But the 2 together dont work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox(); // initializing
    $('#contactForm').validate({ 
        submitHandler: function (form) {

            $.post('/email.php', $('form').serialize());

            $(".popover").fancybox({
                    maxWidth    : 800,
                    maxHeight   : 600,
                    fitToView   : false,
                    width       : '70%',
                    height      : '50%',
                    autoSize    : false,
                    closeClick  : false, 
                    openEffect  : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none' 
            }); 

            jQuery('.popover').trigger('click'); 

        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block popover" href="#successMessage" >Submit</button>
```

PS : I didn't find this specific case with ***validation*** on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do like this, triggering `$(".popover").fancybox({` inside validation `submitHandler: function ()`, you have to run `fancybox` and `validation` code separately.

- Don't need to initialize `$(".fancybox").fancybox();`
- Remove `fancybox` trigger `jQuery('.popover').trigger('click');` from `submitHandler: function ()`
- Remove `class="popover"` and `href="#successMessage"` from form submit button
- run `fancybox` and `validation` code separate
- handle Ajax method `$.post('/email.php', $('form').serialize());`inside `submitHandler: function ()`.
- and trigger `fancybox` after Ajax successful call with `$(".fancybox").trigger('click');`

Following example will give you idea of how to trigger fancybox and form validation inside popup and if validation valid where to handle the Ajax method and calls.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 // initializing
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({
  maxWidth: 800,
  maxHeight: 600,
  fitToView: false,
  width: '70%',
  height: '90%',
  autoSize: false,
  closeClick: false,
  openEffect: 'none',
  closeEffect: 'none'
 });
 $('#contactForm').validate({
  rules: {
   name: {
    required: true
   },
   email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
   }
  },
  messages: {
   name: {
    required: "Please enter your full name."
   },
   email: {
    required: "Please enter your email address."
   }
  },
  submitHandler: function (form) {
     //Handle Ajax Method and success  / error here
   $(".fancybox").trigger('click');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
//Contact Form with validation

<div class="centered-wrap">
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="contactForm">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="name">Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
//Message inside FancyBox
<div class="fancybox" style="display: none;">Confirmation message </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nm8v84c8/5/)

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for clear explanations too. I'll have to dig into how to retrieve the success / failure reply with Ajax, but out of the box, your code does what was needed.